# How to build a database abstraction layer / API / middleware project with grails and are my perceptions possible?

Tags: api, rest, grails, groovy, middleware

I'm thinking about new software design patterns in my plans for new projects. I would like to create a grails API project which abstracts the access to the database layer with the build-in rest API capabilities.

The target is to have a middleware which acts only as an API and some other applications (frontend, mobile frontend, apps...) that use this REST API.

1. I ask myself whether I could get problems or a more complicated development environment with this pattern?
2. What's about validation? Does this work without problems with the REST API features from grails (I need to show the users the errors)?
3. Is there a possibility to create REST clients in my app projects which act like domain class objects? So everyone could work with grails (also plugins) as it would be a normal grails project.
4. Are there any problems known with this pattern?

Comment: You mean similar to http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/developing-spi-applications-using-grails-and-angularjs ?

Comment: @tim_yates i watched this video. Sounds very good, but this video doesn't answer my questions at all. If i understand right, i could do the same like the architecture in the video except that i would use another grails application for frontend instead of angular.js. Point 2 and 3 of my questions are very important for me.

Comment: *Is there a possibility to create REST clients in my app projects which act like domain class objects?* -- Can you elaborate? Also elaborate #2 (You want security validations or api validations)

Comment: A few more links you may find relevant: http://www.bobbywarner.com/2011/06/21/grails-setup/  http://www.slideshare.net/kennethaliu/modularizing-your-grails-application-with-private-plugins-springone-2gx-2012  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891857/best-practice-to-modularise-a-large-grails-app

Comment: And, I don't completely see your full concept, but this plugin seems along the lines of #3? http://grails.org/plugins/gorm-rest-client

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your suggest! Gorm-rest-client looks good.

Answer (score 1):

It's really common to see Single Page Apps where the client side access the server side through REST API's. Remember that Grails marshall functionality accepts a `Map` instead of a domain class, so you can customize your response. For example:

```
def save() {
  ...
  if(instance.hasErrors()) {
    //you can respond the instance errors in any way that you like
    respond([success: false, errors: instance.errors])
  }
  ...
}
```

The REST is a good way to implement your business logic if you have a lot of different clients like you said - mobile, frontend and even desktop.

> Is there a possibility to create REST clients in my app projects wich
>   act like domain class objects? So everyone could work with grails
>   (also plugins) as it would be a normal grails project.

As Andew said, Grails have the [gorm-rest-client](http://grails.org/plugins/gorm-rest-client) that can be used to that. If your client is something different than Grails then you will probably need a different implementation, but REST clients already exists in other languages and frameworks too.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The GORM-REST-CLIENT plugin looks good. What's about i18n and security? How would you do this? I would like to have a grails API project with the business logic and two other grails apps acting as clients. They may be mobile apps or client side apps in future too, so a few more clients. I see a big problem in security concerns. Seems like there is no well tested standardized security pattern or plugin for this. I think the best would be that the grails api project acts as oauth2 provider but maybe the new spring-security-rest plugin is enough...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Twitter uses oauth, but spring-security-rest seems a simple good option too.